# winapi handling multiple keys

Tags: c++, winapi

I need the program to be able to handle multiple keys at the same time. For this I wrote this code:

```
    case WM_KEYDOWN:{
        int debug=pix.getMsg().lParam;
        if(debug>=16 && debug<=23){
            char lpKeyState[256];
            ZeroMemory(lpKeyState,256);
            char input[2];
            int symNum=ToAsciiEx(pix.getMsg().wParam,pix.getMsg().lParam,(BYTE*)lpKeyState,(WORD*)input,0,GetKeyboardLayout(0));
            if(symNum==1)
                keyboardInput.push_back(input[0]);
        }
        break;
    }
```

ToAsciiEx accepts the second parameter of the hardware key scanning code, it says on msdn that WM_KEYDOWN should supposedly pass it through lparam, but something wrong comes to lparam. Where can I get the hardware key scan code or are there other ways to implement this?

Comment: Bits 16-23 of the lParam value are the scan-code, so you'd shift-right by 16 bits then mask with 0xFF

Comment: What makes you believe that scan codes have anything to do with the problem you're trying to solve?  Instead of presenting us with an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) like this, please focus on providing a clearer description of what it is you are actually trying to do.  _I need the program to be able to handle multiple keys at the same time._ does not communicate, not to me at least.

Comment: FYI, if you are going to pass in a `byte[256]` (not `char[256]`!) array into `ToAsciiEx()`, it should not be empty. Call `GetKeyboardState()` first to fill the array. Otherwise, pass in a `NULL` pointer instead. And why are you using a `char[2]` array to receive the output, when the function clearly requires a `WORD[2]` array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown), bits 16 to 23 of `lParam` contain the scan code.

To extract the scan code from `lParam`, you can use the following line:

```
DWORD dwScanCode = ( lParam >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did not understand that this is an offset, the first time I meet this